# line chart implementing AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to draw a line chart with the saved value in a file. I made a slight change to the original demo code given from the AChartEngine website to apply mine. But, there is an error that I can't understand.Please give me some help.

Main code with error: 'setChartSettings(...);' shows an error message.(Many syntax error&return type of method is missing)

```
public class WeightGraph extends AbstractDemoChart {
     ...
    double[] values = getValue();
    int color =  Color.BLUE;
    PointStyle style = PointStyle.CIRCLE;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(color, style);
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Weight", "Time", "Weight(kg)", 0, 10, 30, 70, Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, buildDataset(titles, x, values),
        renderer, "Average temperature");
    return intent;
  }


/*AbstractDemoChart Class, which the code above has extended:*/
 public abstract class AbstractDemoChart implements IDemoChart {
 ...
 protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
      String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
      int labelsColor) {
    renderer.setChartTitle(title);
    renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
    renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi first create new activity as WeightGraph and design your line.xml file with some layout . And then use the following code . You will get the result.

```
 public class WeightGraph extends Activity 
 {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.line);
        LinearLayout line_chart_layout;
        line_chart_layout = findViewById(R.id.line_chart);

        .................             

        double[] values = getValue();
        int color =  Color.BLUE;
        PointStyle style = PointStyle.CIRCLE;
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(color, style);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Weight", "Time", "Weight(kg)", 0, 10, 30, 70,     Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY); 
        renderer.setXLabels(12);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

        line_chart_layout.addView(ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, ui  ldDataset(titles, x, values), renderer, "Average temperature"));

    }
    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
    {
       renderer.setChartTitle(title);
       renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
       renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
       renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
       renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
       renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
       renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
       renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
       renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> z = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // int z[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        List<Double> values_len = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();

        XYSeries xSeries = new XYSeries("");

            for (int i = 0; i < yaxes_value.size(); i++) {
                values.add((double) Long.parseLong(yaxes_value.get(i)));
                xSeries.add(i+1, values.get(i));
            }


        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(xSeries);

        XYSeriesRenderer Xrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        Xrenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC33"));
        Xrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        Xrenderer.setShowLegendItem(true);
        Xrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
        Xrenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(25);
        Xrenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(25f);
//      Xrenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        Xrenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(10);
        Xrenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);
        Xrenderer.setLineWidth(2);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Simple Line Chart");
        mRenderer.setXTitle(X_title);
        mRenderer.setYTitle(Y_title+type);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 50, 100, 40, 20 });// TOP,LEFT,BOTTOM,RIGHT
        mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(2);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(15);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(335);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
//      mRenderer
//              .setYAxisMax((Collections.max(values)) + (Collections.min(values)));
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1);

        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        for (int i = 0; i < Xaxes_value.size(); i++) {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, Xaxes_value.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Xaxes_value.get(i));
        }
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Xrenderer);

        GraphicalView mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
                getBaseContext(), dataset, mRenderer);

        line_chart_layout.addView(mChart);
```